# Xaml - how to use ImageSource from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I have an `ObservableCollection<Item>` and an `Item` contains both a file path and an `ImageSource` of some image from the disk.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MediaListItem>();
```

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Image { get; set; } // Full path to the image
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

However, I am unable to access any of the two attributes and display an image via XAML.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MediaList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" VerticalOptions="Fill"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now I am confused because I am able to output the `string Image` via XAML through a label, but can't display an image from the path at all.

Comment: Try binding to the Image path string instead.  Are the paths urls, full file paths, partial file paths, etc?

Comment: Atleast in code you dont have property called `MediaList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `ImageSource.FromFile()` or `ImageSource.FromUri()`  like this

**In Xaml**

```
<Image  Source="{Binding  ImageSource}"  Aspect="AspectFit"  ></Image>
```

**In Code**

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MediaList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item
            {
                ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("xamarin.png")
            },
            new Item
            {
                ImageSource = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mMod.png"))
            }
        };
```

**The result**

[image]

**Update**

Depending on [Microsoft-Local Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

> Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code...
>
> To use a single image across all apps, the same filename must be used on every platform, and it should be a valid Android resource name (ie. only lowercase letters, numerals, the underscore, and the period are allowed).

For more information take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35618235/4977870)

**Now if you want to display an image without adding it to each platform, you should use [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).**

For example:

1. Create a new folder called `ImagesFolder` in  shared code then add the image to it

   [image]
2. **In Code**, create a new class called `ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter` like this

   ```
   public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter 
   {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {   
       byte[] bytes;
       var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly; // using System.Reflection;

       var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream((string)value); // value = "App1.ImagesFolder.ninja.png"
       using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) // using System.IO; 
       {
           stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
           bytes = ms.ToArray();
       }
       return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
     }
     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
       return null;
     }
   }
   ```

   View Model

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<Item> MediaList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
   {
       new Item
       {
          Image  = "App1.ImagesFolder.ninja.png"
       }
   };
   ```
3. **In Xaml**

   ```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
        x:Class="App1.MainPage">

     <ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
          <local:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter  x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MediaList}" >
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
              <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" />
           </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

   </ContentPage>
   ```

**Related Links**

[ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter](https://github.com/InquisitorJax/Wibci.Xamarin.Forms.Converters/blob/master/Wibci.Xamarin.Forms.Converters/ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter.cs)

[Shared Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#shared-resources)

[How to load binary images in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479653/4977870)

Comment: I suppose it's not gonna work if the image is somewhere randomly on the disk (e.g Desktop), but only if it's in a subfolder of the project?

Comment: @Bowser I have modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change `ImageSource` type to `String`

```
public class Item
{
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Usage

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item() { ImageSource = "*THE URL OF IMAGE*" });
ListView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: As you may see above, I had a string (path to the file) already, but that one doesn't work when using `Binding Image`, for whatever reason. In other words, whether I change it to a string or not, it's the same (as I already tried it).

Comment: did you tried this code `List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item() { ImageSource = "*THE URL OF IMAGE*" });
ListView.ItemsSource = items;`

Comment: you can use image from the disk by starting the path by `@"File://"`

Comment: I concur with Ahmed's answer. I have a image path string property in vmodel as under that binds to Image in XAML:                                                                                           
 public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.text;
            }

            set
            {
                this.text = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
            }
        }