# Why cant I databind a StreamImageSource in XAML and how to bind an Image properly?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

```
   <Image Source="{Binding s, Mode=OneWay}"></Image>
```

with a StreamImageSource-Property:

```
 public ImageSource s { get; set; }
```

Throws following exception:

> Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented' [0:]
> ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid:
> Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

I wonder why this happens? I guess I have to create a Converter, but I dont know what I am supposed to convert? Which argument is correct for Image.source ?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image to each platform,you could use `ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("xxx.png")`.

If you put it in the forms project and set it `Build Action` as `EmbeddedResource`,you could use `ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(your class).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)`

You could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images.

And here is an answer which have achieve the two methods above.You could refer to it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315412/10768653

Comment: Sadly I cant use Uri or a File, Im using a picture that the user selected from their own gallery
Thats why I am also handling with a StreamImageSource

Answer (score 0):

[It seems like Streams get disposed and closed as soon as one uses them to create a source.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4498c6d-6069-4611-b933-c3a2040cca88/image-disposes-source-stream?forum=xamarinforms) Thats why the Image data was "invalid", because there was no image to read from a closed stream. My solution was to create a copy from the stream everytime I use it.

```
 ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()));
```